# Are there any compounds with these properties?

Tags: electrochemistry, decomposition

I'm looking for a chemical compound that satisfies the following criteria:

1. Solid at room temperature
2. Decomposes into gases, primarily oxygen when supplied with an electrical current, preferrably exothermically.
3. Kinetically stable

Any ideas?

Comment: Will potassium ozonide do?

Comment: @mcchucklezz Sorry. I withdrew the comment. Thought this was a duplicate.